# Should I use latest versions of libraries / modules when building an Production Image via Dockerfile?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, google-cloud-run, linux-containers

as mentioned in the title i am asking for a **best practise advise**, if i should **install** the latest version of a library or **module** (e.g. for Python), when **building an Production Image via Dockerfile** or specific version or should i do it total differently?

Right now i use install commands like so to get python modules:

```
RUN pip3 install selenium
RUN pip3 install bs4
RUN pip3 install pandas
```

in my Dockerfile.

My doubts are based on the fear, that my Production Image could be different form the one on my Testing-stage. To complete my scenario: i use Cloudrun on GCP to build my images.

Pls provide your best practise advise, how to deal with (python)-modules when building an image for Production.

Comment: It's good practice to specify versions rather then default to latest. This ensures that your container images are reproducible; you want to be able to rebuild the image and know that it will not only use the same versions of any OS, OS packages, Python and Python packages but also your code. You should endeavor to use the same image version for testing and production too.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to pin versions depending on how you release. When creating an image for testing, I release it with a testing tag. Users testing with your software can use that tag to pull the contents. After that tag has be QA'd you can re-tag that image to mark it as production ready. If you find issues with that tag in production, revert to the older tag. Within the images, I would dump a copy of `pip freeze` to make it easy to inspect what is installed in each release.

Comment: thanks @DazWilkin & @flakes! if i get you both right, you would also advise to release the testing-image if QA´d and NOT build a dedicated production image?

Comment: @hannes_rd Yup exactly. The testing image with the new content on it eventually becomes the production image. You don't need to recreate it from scratch to be considered production. It should be considered production after confirming the software acts as you would expect it to. You can also combine that strategy with pinned versions. You don't need to use one of those strategies in isolation.

Comment: @flakes thanks a lot for claryfing! :) will do so from now on.